# iOS - How to dynamically update UICollectionViewCell size after label text changed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a cell in UICollectionView

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell: myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell
        // cell.descrption is an UILabel
        cell.description.text = newText
        return cell
    }
```

and

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.width*0.95, collectionView.bounds.height/4)       
    }
```

My question is:

`newText` is acquired from the web. So it's dynamically changed. After the cell's text is set to newText, how should I adjust the label so that it has the right size to fit "newText" and how should I adjust the cell's size and display it on the screen?

I noticed that `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` is invoked before `cellForItemAtIndexPath()`. Therefore, I can't calculate the size for nextText within `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a great way to check the what text size would be in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()`,
as you already know that `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` is invoked before `cellForItemAtIndexPath()` you can have a dummy cell having same information. e.g you may refer to my code which i used in `UITableView` and implement according to your requirement.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var myLabel:UILabel!
    var labelText = myTextArray[indexPath.row]
    var constraint = CGSizeMake(662, MAXFLOAT);
    var attributes = NSDictionary(dictionary: [UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute, size: 12):NSFontAttributeName])
    var textSize:CGRect = NSString(string: labelText).boundingRectWithSize(constraint, options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    myLabel.text = labelText
    return myLabel.frame.size.height
}
```

you can do same to achieve size in `UICollectionView` as both share same inheritance.
so there would be no problem.
Even you can return custom height depending upon the number of characters in your text. like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var myLabel:UILabel!

    var labelText = myTextArray[indexPath.row]
    if count(labelText) > 0 && count(labelText) <30
        return 40;
    else if count(labelText)>31 && count(labelText)<60
        return 70;
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my problem is that the text is acquired from the web. Therefore I don't know what the text will be as the text is dynamically changed and I can not create a dummy cell during `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()`.

Comment: You'd put the UI update in the completion handler of the HTTP class which pulls the data.

Comment: just `realodData` from completion handler. it would reload again.